# EV controller output signals

Tags: motor, dac, digital-potentiometer

I am designing an electric vehicle controller for a university project. The motor driver varies the speed according to an analog voltage (0V-12V).
My queston is, should I use a digital potentiometer followed by a buffer or a DAC to change the digital signal output from the microcontroller to an analog voltage for the motor driver, I found both close in terms of cost and complexity, and the resolution of the digital potentiometer is good for my requirements.
So which would be better? Did I miss an important point of comparison?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much the same really as you can see:

[image: DigiPot Vs DAC]

You will be able to find higher res DACs but if a digipot is OK for you then fine.

You can look here to see if there is any more information which is useful:

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/4/4025.html

Check if you have a DAC embedded in the uController which could save design time.

Comment: This is great, thanks